# Why does is my AVL tree delete function not balanced?

Tags: c++

My delete function does not work properly. when it delete the node it doesn't rebalance the whole tree. Sometime it balance the left subtree but omit the whole right subtree. The code is quite long

```
class AVLTree
{
public:
    void insert(const DataType &item);
    void graph(ostream &out) const;
    void remove(DataType &value);
private:
    class AVLNode
    {
    public:
        DataType data;
        int balanceFactor;
        AVLNode *left;
        AVLNode *right;
        AVLNode():balanceFactor(0),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
        AVLNode(DataType item):balanceFactor(0), data(item),left(NULL), right(NULL){}
    };
    typedef AVLNode* AVLNodePointer;
    AVLNodePointer myRoot;
    int height(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
    int different(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
    AVLNodePointer ll_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent);
    AVLNodePointer rr_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent);
    AVLNodePointer lr_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent);
    AVLNodePointer rl_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent);
    AVLNodePointer balance_tree(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
    AVLNodePointer insertAux(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer &subtreeRoot,const DataType &value);
    AVLNodePointer findmin(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
    AVLNodePointer deleteAux(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp,DataType &value);
    void graphAux(ostream &out,int indent,  AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer subtreePtr) const;
                            };
template<typename DataType>
int AVLTree<DataType>::height(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp)
{
     int h=0;
     if(temp!=NULL)
 {
    int left_height=height(temp->left);
    int right_height=height(temp->right)
    int max_height =max(left_height,right_height);
    h=max_height +1;
 }
 return h;
}

template<typename DataType>
int AVLTree<DataType>::different(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp)
{
int left_height=height(temp->left);
int right_height=height(temp->right);
temp->balanceFactor=left_height-right_height;
return temp->balanceFactor;
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::ll_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp;
temp=parent->left;
parent->left=temp->right;
temp->right=parent;
return temp;
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::rr_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp;
temp=parent->right;
parent->right=temp->left;
temp->left=parent;
return temp;
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::lr_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp;
temp=parent->left;
parent->left=rr_rotation(temp);
return ll_rotation(parent);
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::rl_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp;
temp=parent->right;
parent->right=ll_rotation(temp);
return rr_rotation(parent);
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::balance_tree(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp)
{
temp->balanceFactor=different(temp);

if(temp->balanceFactor>1)
{
    if(different(temp->left)>0)
    {
        temp=ll_rotation(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        temp=lr_rotation(temp);
    }
}
else if(temp->balanceFactor<-1)
{
    if(different(temp->right)>0)
    {
        temp=rl_rotation(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        temp=rr_rotation(temp);
    }
}
return temp;  //no balance needed
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::findmin(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp)
{
    if(temp->left==NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        findmin(temp->left);
    }
}
template<typename DataType>
void AVLTree<DataType>::remove(DataType &value)
{
    deleteAux(myRoot,value);
}

template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::deleteAux(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp,DataType &value)
{

if(temp==NULL)
{
    return temp;
}
if (value<temp->data)
{
    temp->left=deleteAux(temp->left,value);
    temp=balance_tree(temp);
}
else if(value>temp->data)
{
    temp->right=deleteAux(temp->right,value);
    temp= balance_tree(temp);
}
else
{
    if(temp->left==NULL && temp->right==NULL)
    {
        AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp1;
        temp1=temp;
        delete temp1;
        temp=NULL;
    }
    else if(temp->left==NULL)
    {
        AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp1=temp;
        temp=temp->right;
        delete temp1;
        temp1=NULL;

    }
    else if(temp->right==NULL)
    {
        AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp1=temp;
        temp=temp->left;
        delete temp1;
        temp1=NULL;

    }
    else
    {
        AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp1=findmin(temp->right);
        temp->data=temp1->data;
        temp->right=deleteAux(temp->right, temp1->data);
    }

}
return temp;
}
```

Just edit forgot to add delete function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to debug through your code using a debugger to see what is going on.

One thing that jumps out is that you don't use the return value from `deleteAux` in your first call, so if deleteAux changes what the root should be you won't have the right root value. Try changing your `remove` function to:

```
myRoot = deleteAux(myRoot,value);
```